AWS VPC: Lambda functions experiencing slow performance and timeouts
I recently modified my VPC configuration, and now I'm experiencing significant performance issues with my Lambda functions. Here's my current setup:
VPC Configuration:

4 subnets total:

3 subnets (eu-central-1a, eu-central-1b, eu-central-1c) connected to a route table with:

Internet Gateway (IGW) for public internet access

VPC Endpoint (VPCE) for S3 access



1 additional public subnet (in eu-central-1a) connected to a separate route table with the same network connections





Lambda Function:
My Lambda function performs the following tasks:

Connects to a database
Reads a CSV file from S3
Performs calculations
Writes results back to the database



Issue:
After the VPC changes, I'm noticing severe performance degradation:
Connections to S3 and the database are taking anywhere from a few seconds to over 2 minutes
This is causing other functions to fail due to timeouts
Logs show that the connection times are highly variable and unpredictable. I'm not certain if this is related to the VPC changes or if there's another underlying issue.
Questions:
What could be causing these slow connection times within my VPC?
Are there any specific VPC configurations or best practices I should check to improve Lambda performance?
How can I diagnose if this is a networking issue or something else?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You keep saying you think this is related to VPC changes, but you don't list anywhere in your question what changes you made too the VPC. Please edit your question to specify exactly what changes were made.

Check which subnets your Lambda function can connect to. It might be that it sometimes connects to a public subnet or sometimes to a private subnet. This can cause problems due to the different routing rules on the subnets.

Yes! it solve the problem! Before that I cancelled the connection between the Internet Gateway and the public subnet and it also helped, but sometimes it takes long time again (while there are many requests from few Lambda function's executions.
